# Double.NaN arithmetic differences between x64 and arm64

Tags: c#

I have come across some code in one of our services which fails unit tests on a Mac Studio (with arm64 architecture).

It seems to be due to differences in the way `Double.NaN` is treated if you perform arithmetic on it.

I have reproduced the relevant behaviour into the following unit test which now passes on both x64 and arm64 due to the architecture specific assertions. Can anyone explain what's going on here?

```cs
[TestCase]
public void TestNaN()
{
    double nanDouble = double.NaN;
    
    int testInt = (int)(2 * nanDouble);

    if (RuntimeInformation.ProcessArchitecture == Architecture.Arm64)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(0, testInt);
    }
    
    if (RuntimeInformation.ProcessArchitecture == Architecture.X64)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(-2147483648, testInt);
    }
}
```

Comment: C# spec: *If the value of the operand is NaN or infinite, the result of the conversion is an unspecified value of the destination type*.  "Unspecified" means that architecture-specific behavior is by design.

Comment: Note that  IEEE 754 specifies that when converting a `NaN` to an integral type, an invalid operation exception of some kind is signalled. If you used `checked` in C# when converting a `NaN` to an integral type, you will indeed see an exception.